# MDX - Creating a dynamic grouping member?

Tags: ssas, mdx

Category {A,B,C}

Value

**Currently** I can get:

```
Category    Value
--------    -----
A           100
B           200
C           300
```

What I'd *like* to get is:

```
Category    Value
--------    -----
A           100
B           200
C           300
D           500
```

Where D is the value of B + C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, this was actually incredibly easy...

```
with member [Category].[Name].[D] as
    [Category].[Name].[B] + [Category].[Name].[C]

select
    {[Measures].[Value]} on columns,
    [Category].[Name].allmembers on rows
from [Cube]
```

Result:

```
Category    Value
--------    -----
A           100
B           200
C           300
D           500
```