# Adding an extra row to an MDX result set

Tags: ssas, olap, mdx, cube, dimensions

I have a very simple MDX query that retuns the contents of a dimension.

I would like to inject one more row to the result set as part of the MDX.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697585/mdx-creating-a-dynamic-grouping-member ? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a calculated member of the dimension.  Suppose I have 4 members of region built into my cube: East, West South and Central.

```
 SELECT
 {[Profit].[Sales]}  ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY [Market].Generations(2).Members ON ROWS
 FROM [Basic]
```

will give me the sales over the 4 regions.

If I add a dummy calculated member to the region, I can get one extra row of results.

```
 WITH
 MEMBER [Market].[Dummy] AS
   '0',
   SOLVE_ORDER = 0
 SELECT
 {[Margin].[Sales]} ON COLUMNS,
 NON EMPTY Union(
   [Market].Generations(2).Members,
   {[Market].[Dummy]}) ON ROWS
 FROM [Basic]
```

Answer (score 0):

no, it has to be a member of some dimension